# Can I use IOS5 Appearance in only some cases, to preserve the back arrow?

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, appearance

I am using the appearance protocol `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];` to color all my buttons.  The problem I am running into is that there are some rare cases where I have to create a custom back button like so, UIButton* customBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];, inorder to have it callback to an event when pressed.  When I use the appearance protocol it removes the arrow shape.

Does anyone know a way to get back the arrow shape?  Or is there a way to specify in the appearance to not effect a certain class?

Answer (score 0):

The only accepted way I know of is to use an image. Also, I think you should be using `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` instead of the numeric value.